# JXLS + SXSSF - How to generate Excel file without including the template along with the actual generated report?

Tags: java, streaming, apache-poi, jxls

I'm trying to use JXLS's `PoiTransformer` in order to generate a really huge report; the problem is, all the examples I've found so far generate an excel file with two sheets, one containing the original, unmodified, template, and another containing the actual result. Is there any way of ommiting the first sheet, mantaining only the result?

This is my current code:

```
        PoiContext context = new PoiContext();
        context.putVar("params", this.montaParametros(rel, filtro, opcoes, dados));
        context.putVar("dados", this.converteDados(rel, dados));

        Workbook template = WorkbookFactory.create(resource.getInputStream());
        PoiTransformer transformer = PoiTransformer.createSxssfTransformer(template, 5, false);

        AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
        List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();

        Area xlsArea = xlsAreaList.get(0);
        // xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Template!A1"), context); // Tried forcing it to use the original sheet as the output sheet, but it does not overwrite things properly
        xlsArea.applyAt(new CellRef("Result!A1"), context); // Writes into a new sheet, but that's not what is desired

        Workbook processado = transformer.getWorkbook();
        processado.write(out);
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, silly me, it seems I can just remove the unwanted sheets before writing to disk; I thought SXSSF would have hindered that in some way, but it seems to just work:

```
    Workbook processado = transformer.getWorkbook();
    processado.removeSheetAt(0);
    processado.write(out);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I was going through the same problem.
It appears that indeed, JxlsHelper remove by default the template sheet.